# Misalignement and interword spacing with mono font

Tags: spacing, xetex, indentation, fontspec, typewriter

I'm making a document with XeLaTeX and I would like to use a mono TTF font (Liberation Mono) and a special (reversed) indentation for my paragraphs.

I don't understand some things about words spacing and indentation. I made the following LaTeX code to perform a test :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,13pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Mono}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Cras sit amet est sit amet urna tincidunt consectetur 
eget ut felis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus 
orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam dapibus, 

\setlength{\parindent}{-5ex}
\setlength{\leftskip}{5ex}%

\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Cras sit amet est sit amet urna tincidunt consectetur 
eget ut felis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus 
orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam dapibus,

\setlength{\parindent}{-5em}
\setlength{\leftskip}{5em}%

\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Cras sit amet est sit amet urna tincidunt consectetur 
eget ut felis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus 
orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam dapibus,

\end{document}
```

and I have the following results:

[image]

I note these things :

1. In the first paragraph : For what reason are the characters not aligned vertically. The word interspace should be constant (with a mono font) , but it is not.
2. In the second paragraph : The characters are not indented correctly. normally an indentation of 5ex should give a length of 5 character. But there is a difference and the indented lines are misaligned against the first.
3. In the third paragraph : The indentation length of 5em give a bigger indentation than with 5ex. But with a mono font, the length ex (width of an 'x') and em  (width of an 'm') should be the same.

**Do you have any idea on how to fix the interword spacing as a constant, why I have these misalignement with my tests paragraphs and what is wrong with my observations (If there is something wrong)?**

Comment: ex is usually roughly the _height_ of an x and em is (roughly) the width of an M but both are arbitrary lengtsh assigned in the font metrics and not necessarily tied to any character

Comment: Also, LaTeX doesn't use fixed space width by default even if the font is monospace. You need some kind of verbatim environment or `\obeyspaces` to make spaces have their natural width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you're forgetting `\frenchspacing`.

Second, 1ex need not be the same as 1em.

Third, 1ex and 1em are not multiples of the character width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LiberationMono}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\raggedright
\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Cras sit amet est sit amet urna tincidunt consectetur 
eget ut felis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus 
orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam dapibus, 

\setlength{\parindent}{-5\fontcharwd\font`A}
\setlength{\leftskip}{5\fontcharwd\font`A}

\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}: consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Cras sit amet est sit amet urna tincidunt consectetur 
eget ut felis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus 
orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam dapibus,

\end{document}
```

[image]

The font setup is because I don't have Liberation Mono installed system-wide.

Just for information, here's the output of

```
1ex = \the\dimexpr1ex

1em = \the\dimexpr1em

A = \the\fontcharwd\font`A
```

[image]

Note also that the option `13pt` does nothing at all and the font would be 10pt. I changed it to `12pt`.